# Android: Disabling onLocationChanged() after getting current location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm currently coding a GPS application on Android. I've successfully getting the current location of the user, but it wont stop updating the location. How do I stop the onLocationChanged() once I get the user's current location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `removeUpdates()` for removing any current registration for location updates of the current activity with the given `LocationListener`. After getting the `Location` for the first time you can `unregister` `LocationListner` updates by,

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
listener = null;
```

Comment: is this possible to be applied on the onPause() method too?

Comment: yup you can perform it anywhere in your Activity, just make sure you have your Listener and LocationManager global to the Activity.

Comment: @LalitPoptani i tried using `locationManager.removeUpdates(listener) `,but getting error..Can u have a look at this example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466401/windowmanager-badtokenexception-unable-to-add-windowwhy-i-am-getting-this-exce?noredirect=1#comment47095921_29466401)