# "WindowManager BadTokenException-Unable to add window"Why i am getting this exception while using google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, exception, android-asynctask

I am using google map to show(pin) different places.After showing different palces when hit the back button it redirects to my home screen.Around 10-15 seconds later my application gets closed.I believe that the location updates is still running in the background which causes this error.How to stop updating the activity in the background?

```
    package com.bar.start;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
    import com.bar.barapp.R;
    import com.bar.location.Loc;
    import com.bar.location.Webcall;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.print.PrintAttributes;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

     private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
     protected ConnectionDetector connectionDetector;
     public Boolean isInternetPresent;
     private String[] places;
     public static Loc [] getloc;
     private LocationManager locationManager;
     private Location loc;

     static HttpEntity entityResponse = null;
     GoogleMap map;
     MarkerOptions mp;
     Activity activity;
     Context context;
     LocationListener listener;
     Double lat,lon;
    final   String Googlekey="APikey" ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        int locationCount = 0;
        connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        isInternetPresent = connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);

     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

      map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        map.clear();
        lat=location.getLatitude();
        lon=location.getLongitude();

        Googleapicall exeTask = new Googleapicall();
          exeTask.execute();

          mp = new MarkerOptions();

           mp.position(new LatLng(lat, lon));
           map.addMarker(mp);
           mp.title("My Location");
   p.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
          new LatLng(lat, lon), 13));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }



    public class Googleapicall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

    {


        Loc statStr = null;
         Loc[] statInfoResult = null;
         ArrayList<Loc> SIArrayList = new ArrayList<Loc>();

        private ProgressDialog Dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationActivity.this);
            Dialog.setMessage(LocationActivity.this.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.loading));
            Dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String result = "";
            try 
            {

                if(isInternetPresent)

                {
                getloc=Webcall.getdet(lat,lon,Googlekey);
                result = "Success";
                System.out.println("getloc "+getloc.length);

                }


                else 
                {
                    result = "Failure";
                }
            } 


            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = "Failure";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            Loc lc=new Loc();

            try {

                if(result.contains("Success"))
                {

                    mp=new MarkerOptions();

                    for(int i=0;i<getloc.length;i++)
                    {
                        Double lati=getloc[i].latitudes;
                        Double longi=getloc[i].longitudes;
                           map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                              .title("Nearbyplace")
                              .position(
                                new LatLng(lati,longi))
                              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.small)));
                    }
                }

                } 
            catch 
            (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();    

            }

            Dialog.dismiss();

        }

    }


}


04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@42ea1380 is not valid; is your activity running?
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:796)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at com.bar.start.LocationActivity$Googleapicall.onPreExecute(LocationActivity.java:194)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at com.bar.start.LocationActivity.onLocationChanged(LocationActivity.java:104)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:255)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:184)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:200)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
04-06 11:09:53.768: E/AndroidRuntime(5188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: cancel() your TimerTask when hinishing you maps activity

Comment: @pskink i tried finish() but nothing happened, .cancel() is not coming while i hit ctrl+space in eclipse.

Comment: see: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()

Comment: @pskink but here no timertask is used....

Comment: @pskink `@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     if (isFinishing() != true) return;
    
 }` i think this code required somthing like this,but this is not working either

Comment: ooops, i meant AsyncTask, not TimerTask

Comment: @pskink `Googleapicall exeTask = new Googleapicall();
   exeTask.cancel(true);`  where should i give that in above code?

Comment: when your activity stops or is destroyed

Comment: @pskink `@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  
  super.onDestroy();
  final Googleapicall exeTask = new Googleapicall(); 
  
  Dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
           public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            exeTask.cancel(true);
               //finish();
           }
     });
  
 }` same error is coming

Comment: you have to `cancel()` pending `Googleapicall exeTask`, not to create a new one...

Comment: @pskink  `@Override protected void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); Dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { exeTask.cancel(true); // finish(); } });` still same error is coming  }

Answer (score 1):

Globally declare this value.

```
int i=0;
```

In the above code make the following changes.So that it will update only once.(windowmanager badtokenexception-unable to add window)this exception will not happen again.But i dont know whether it is right method to do.If anyone got better answer,you are welcome.

```
@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


               for(;i<=0;i++)
               {

                   map.clear();

                    lat=location.getLatitude();
                    lon=location.getLongitude();

                      mp = new MarkerOptions();

                       mp.position(new LatLng(lat, lon));
                       map.addMarker(mp);
                       mp.title("My Location");

                   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                              new LatLng(lat, lon), 13));

                            Googleapicall exeTask = new Googleapicall();
                              exeTask.execute();

               }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try ,

1. create boolean static variable ,

   ```
   private static boolean isActivityOpen = false ;
   ```
2. update the value at onCreate()

   ```
   isActivityOpen  = true;
   ```
3. Check value at dialog show / dismiss method

   ```
   if(isActivityOpen )
   {
     Dialog.show();
   }
   ```
4. Disable value in onDestroy()

   ```
   isActivityOpen  = false;
   ```

Comment: you have this dialog "private ProgressDialog Dialog;" ,  you need to make it show or dismiss only when activity is running